# At what point are @PreDestroy, destroyMethod, and disposableBean.destroy() executed?

Tags: java, spring

You can use either of these to define a method to be executed right before bean destruction (examples are borrowed from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-shutdown-callbacks)):

`@PreDestroy`

```java
@Component
public class Bean1 {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println(
          "Callback triggered - @PreDestroy.");
    }
}
```

`destroyMethod`:

```java
public class Bean3 {

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println(
          "Callback triggered - bean destroy method.");
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ShutdownHookConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public Bean3 initializeBean3() {
        return new Bean3();
    }
}
```

and `disposableBean.destroy()`:

```java
@Component
public class Bean2 implements DisposableBean {

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
          "Callback triggered - DisposableBean.");
    }
}
```

I have these questions (I hope it's not too broad):

1. When are these callbacks triggered other than after an explicit `context.close()` invocation (which, I'll venture to suggest, doesn't happen often in production code)? If Spring registers those callbacks with something like

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    // destroy method logic
}));
```

I got my answer, but I'm not sure it's what actually happens

2. Does Spring guarantee any order of execution of those callbacks (theoretically, I can provide a separate destroy method using each of those ways, and the implementations may be interdependent)? Again, if Spring adds a shutdown hook with `addShutdownHook()`, I got my answer since the method's documentation explicitly says

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some **unspecified order** and let them run concurrently.

but I'm not sure it's what actually happens

Comment: Spring only registers 1 shutdown hook and that is to close the `ApplicationContext` which in turn will trigger the destroy methods. If my memory serves me well the order will always be `DisposableBean` interface, destroy method on declaration, then annotations (but you can test that fairly easy). The order of bean destruction is the inverse order of bean creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will [register only 1 shutdown hook](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#L1005C13-L1005C13), which will simply close the `ApplicationContext` so it can shutdown properly. It does this by simply calling the `close` method (or rather the internal `doClose()` method) this ensures [a graceful shutdown of the context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html#beans-factory-shutdown).

The beans are destroyed in the reverse order as they were created, so the bean that got created the first will be destroyed the last.

Next there is the question of the destroy methods order invocation as there are multiple flavors. This is clearly described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects)

> Destroy methods are called in the same order:
>
> 1. Methods annotated with `@PreDestroy`
> 2. `destroy()` as defined by the `DisposableBean` callback interface
> 3. A custom configured `destroy()` method

Comment: Thank you very much! The author of the Spring Start Here book, Laurentiu Spilca, said you shouldn't rely on `@PreDestroy` because Spring may fail to close the context. But if it's a shutdown hook, it's not up for Spring to close it or not anymore. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Also, more broadly, can you rely on either of those methods to do essential clean-up job? If not, why?

Comment: A shutdownhook is always an best effort and it can still be that the JVM decides to terminate because a method keeps the JVM hanging. Also if you abruptly kill the process it won't work either. In general yes you can but there are cases that it won't (or might not work).